# Python subprocess output

Tags: python, subprocess, bazel

I use subprocess in python to capture result from a bazel aplication tensorflow.

```
import subprocess
cmd = ["bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image"]
pipe = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
output = pipe.communicate()[0]
print "Result: ", output
```

The problem is that the result appears in the terminal and I can not capture it in the variable 'output'

And returns Result: (nothing)

Comment: Try also capturing stderr with `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` and `output, err = pipe.communicate()` and see what is in err.

Comment: As @sberry says - the output's likely going to `stderr`... Also, when using the `subprocess` module, you can use the `check_output` wrapper around `Popen`, eg: `output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)`

Comment: As an aside, there is no need for `shell=True` here. The command is in a list and can be executed without running through a subshell.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works with stderr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved in comments:

```
Try also capturing stderr with stderr=subprocess.PIPE and output, err = pipe.communicate() and see what is in err. – sberry
```